# Attiny4 - Possible Errata Found With PWM

Tags: attiny

I have searched the AtTiny data sheet and not found anything about this. I'm experiencing a weird PWM bug. When I expect 100% on I'm getting less. I'm using an inverted PWM scheme, so setting it equal to 0 should be full on, but my scope shows a ~95% on duty pulse.

Below I posted applicable setup code, then the function I call occasionally in my main() to change the PWM rate... When I set the OCR0B=0, I do not get a full on PWM.

I'll also note all other PWM settings appear to work correctly, the duty cycle matches what is expected.

Anyone want to take a look to check I'm sane before I complain to Microchip/Atmel?

```
//Setup Pins:
DDRB =  DDRB |  0b00000010;     //set B1 output and B2 to input.
PUEB = PUEB |   0b00000100;     //Pullup on B2

//Setup Timer:
//output pin is OC0B (PB1)
//Set PWM Fast Mode 8 Bit, enable output on all PWM pins (only 1 on tiny5).
TCCR0A = 1<<COM0A1 | 1<<COM0B1 | 1<<COM0A0 | 1<<COM0B0 | 1<<WGM01;  //COM0A0 COM0B0 set to 1 for inverting PWM.
//Set PWM top [ICR0] to 5bit (this allows effective 31khz pwm)
ICR0 = TOP_PWM; //Set TOP...
//Set PWM Mode Fast 8 bit & No pre-scaler.
TCCR0B =  1<<CS00 | 1<<WGM02 | 1<<WGM03;
OCR0B = TOP_PWM; //Start with 0 output.

//Setup INO0 (External Interrupt):
EICRA = 1<<ISC00 | 1<<ISC01;    //Enable rising edge interrupt
EIMSK = 1<<INT0;                //Enable INT0

 ----------------------------------------------------------------

/******************************************
* Function to decide what speed to set.
* NOTE: All alterations to motor speed should
*       be done in this function!
* Also note that inverse PWM is used,
* so 0 is full speed, and TOP_PWM is stopped.
******************************************/
void speedLogic()
{
    //Speed logic
    if      (speed_state == 0)
        speed = TOP_PWM;//Off
    else if (speed_state == 1)
        speed = 24;     //Slow
    else if (speed_state == 2)
        speed = 16;     //Med
    else if (speed_state == 3)
        speed = 0;      //Fast (3=91% Otherwise 0=100%)
    else
        speed = TOP_PWM;

    //Set PWM Reg
    OCR0B = speed;

    //Increment State Variable
    speed_state++;
    if (speed_state > 3)
        speed_state = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, it is a feature not a bug. Citing from the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8127-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny4-ATtiny5-ATtiny9-ATtiny10_Datasheet.pdf) (page 94):

> The extreme values for the OCR0x registers represents special cases
>   when generating a PWM waveform output in the Fast PWM mode. If the
>   OCR0x is set equal to BOTTOM (0x0000) the output will be a narrow
>   spike for each TOP+1 timer clock cycle. Setting the OCR0x equal to TOP
>   will result in a constant high or low output (depending on the
>   polarity of the output which is controlled by COM0x[1:0]).

This describes your observation pretty well. With 5 bit PWM (32 steps, right?) the duty cycle should be 97 % (not 95 %), but it is probably good enough for *approximately*.

Comment: This makes sense, but seems odd? So then to get a 0 PWM output, I would need to flip the COM0x0 bit? I have never seen a PWM setup quite like that.

Comment: This or stop the timer or change the WG mode or something else (there is probably a few other possibilities). It is not completely clear to me from the datasheet, but I guess the waveform generator uses the same logic as a OCF0x flag, that is action happens at the start of next tick _after_ the match. Maybe strange or impractical, but probably allows more simple HW implementation. (I suspect that for full 0 to 100 %, the HW would have to implement one of edge value as a special case.)